# WebSocket Server Implementation at Xamarin Studio 5 Android Project

Tags: android, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on WebSocket server implementation on Xamarin for an Android project, here I have Monoframework MDK 3.10.0.23 and Xamarin.android 4.18 which are latest ones.

For server implementation I'm using `HttpListener` and `HttpListenerContext` and evaluating the `context.Request.IsWebSocketrequest`, which is always getting `false`, when I run it on a Google Nexus 10.

```
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WS Server Started Waiting for connection");
            HttpListenerContext httpListenerContext = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();

            if (!httpListenerContext.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                WebSocketContext webSocketContext;
                Console.WriteLine("Got a Valid WebSocket connection request");
                try
                {
                    webSocketContext = await httpListenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol:null);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    httpListenerContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    httpListenerContext.Response.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e);
                    return;
                }
                WebSocket webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;
                if (webSocket == null)
                    Console.WriteLine ("WebSocket obj is null");
                //ProcessRequest(httpListenerContext);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Got a Bad WebSocket connection request");
                httpListenerContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                httpListenerContext.Response.Close();
            }
        }
```

Please help and suggest the problem here creating the `HttpListener` object for http:// local host at 9090

Answer (score 0):

websockets initiates connection via http with the request to upgrade. if the server do not reply with the 101 response code, it is a sign that there is a problem in connection. the request to connect via websockets uses ws://yourdomain.com/nameOfApplicationEndPoint or wss in cases of ssl connection. i used this for my android project org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0 and you can get a simple example here http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps

Comment: Hi , my main objective is to implement a WebSocket server using c# for a Android application at latest Xamarin Studio and Xamarin.Android framework updated. Is it possible/Supported ? Another question If possible then how to implement it. Can we use System.Net.WebSockets classes to implement it. Please give some examples. NOTE I am using these : MonoFramework MDk 3.10.0.23 , Xamarin Studio 5.5.3 and Xamarin.Android 4.18.1.3